# Se muere el navegador al cargar un archivo grande

Tags: nodejs, angular, fileupload, multer

resulta que en mi aplicación necesito subir archivo de como máximo 1gb y alojarlos en mi servidor pero sucede que muere el navegador y aparece una imagen que adjunto si los archivos son chicos no hay problema pero sucede que cuando el archivo ocupa mas de 100mb ya muere. Mi aplicacion esta desarollada en Angular como frontend y mi API esta realizada en Nodejs + Expres y la libreria que uso para guardar los archivos es Multer. El problema creo que es angular que no envia el archivo hasta tenerlo cargado todo y luego de eso lo envia a la api alguien sabe como solucionar el problema?

mi api se ve algo como esto  :

```
    var upload = multer({ storage: this.getStorage() })

            .post(`${this.path}/upload`, [authMiddleware, upload.single('image')], this.upload)

public getStorage(): multer.StorageEngine {
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req: RequestWithUser, file, cb) {
            let path = '/home/clients';
            if (req.database) {
                path = path + '/' + req.database + '/resources/' + req.query.type;
            }
            fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true });
            cb(null, path);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            var name: string = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD-THH_mm_ss').toString() + '-' + file.originalname.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
            cb(null, name.replace(/ /g, "-"));
        }
    })
    return storage;
}
```

Y mi front asi html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
          <label for="file" class="control-label">{{'file' | translate | capitalize}}:</label>
          <div class="custom-file">
            <label class="custom-file-label btn btn-action"
              for="customFileLang">{{filename?filename:'Seleccionar archivo'}}</label>
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" lang="es" id="customFileLang" [readonly]="readonly"
              (change)="onFileSelected($event)" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

service

```
  public uploadFile(type: String, file: File) {
let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', Config.apiURL + '/resources/upload?type=' + type, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', this._authService.getToken());
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let formData: any = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', file, file.name);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
      } else {
        reject(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send(formData);
});
```

}

Adjunto la imagen que me da el navegador 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El *data-buffer* de *Node* es de máximo 1GB. Ese GB debe servir para cargar todos los ficheros de la *webapp* y todas sus dependencias, que siendo *Angular* no son pocas. Si tienes que mandar un fichero grande debes hacerlo por *streams*, para aliviar la carga del *buffer*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta tenes algun link para guiarme un poco para por donde comenzar o si no es mucho pedir un ejemplo. Saludos!

Comment: [Este](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/) pequeño ejemplo ilustra cuán sencillo es. En tu caso podrías hacerlo quizás al recibir una *request* en algún *endpoint*. Y [aquí](https://riptutorial.com/node-js/topic/6994/sending-a-file-stream-to-client) te dejo una serie de ejemplos un poco más en profundidad.